GitLab merge request - custom container scan report
I am trying to add a custom scan report for report type "container_scanning" with the goal of displaying the results inside the merge request. The Container image will be scanned using trivy.
Custom report gets generated by my own python code from the trivy results - it looks good imo:

It followed this example: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/security/security-reports/-/blob/master/samples/container-scanning.json
Job config:
artifacts:
    reports:
      container_scanning: custom_report.json
    paths:
      - custom_report.json

File gets uploaded to artifacts:

I followed the format like documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/#reports-json-format
Still, nothing displayed in the merge request. It works with code_quality though.
Any idea what am I missing? I read the docs and tried a lot with ChatGPT - still no luck :/

Maybe the reason is we do not have GitLab "Ultimate" 

Yes that was it!
